# hover over image unwraps a hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seen these on many sites. Basically, I'm creating a portfolio and I have a number of divs (squares in grid format) showing screenshots of my projects. I want to be able to hover over each project with my mouse which will in turn slide in a previously hidden div revealing specific information about that particular project.

Basically, I am looking for something simple like this: http://iamyuna.com/

Notice if you hover over each shape (i.e. project), it quickly "unwraps" to reveal another image underneath. This may be a bad example since what I want is for the description to show up instead of another picture. However, I love how quickly it unwraps to show the hidden content.

Below is how my html is laid out. Would it be possible to implement something similar for my own work? If you guys can help me get started on this or suggest keywords to start with (I've been searching for a tutorial for hours but can't find one), I'd really appreciate it. Thank you.

```
<article class="project" data-id="248">
    <div class="project-mask">
        <div class="thumbnail">
             <img src="image.jpg">
             <div class="description">
                  <h2>Title</h2>
                  <p>Description</p>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: This would be easier in CSS.  Put a layer on top that has `:hover { display: none; }`
If you want the transition effect, take a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vary basic implementation:

```
$('.thumbnail').hover(function () {
    $('.description', this).stop().animate({
        bottom: 0
    }, 200);
}, function () {
    $('.description', this).stop().animate({
        bottom: -100
    }, 200);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LAkmA/

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you! But can you explain why `.description` is set to `bottom:-105px` instead of `bottom:100px`?

Comment: Do I have to put the jQuery in between `$(document).ready(function($){` and `});`?

Comment: It's just a quick example so it's not perfect, bottom should be `-100px` of course. You can put your code between `$(function() { ... })` to make sure code is executed when DOM tree is loaded. Or you can also put the script at the end of the body so it goes last then you don't need `$(function() { ... })`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this just in CSS with something like this:

```
.thumbnail img { display:block; }
.thumbnail div.description { display:none; }

.thumbnail:hover img {display:none; }
.thumbnail:hover div.description {display:block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".thumbnail img").hover(function(){ $(".description").css("display", "block"); }, function(){ $(".description").css("display", "none");});
</script>
```

Note : this is done using jQuery and you need to set .description's display to none

also it would be much better to use IDs instead of classes and that would be something like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#IMG1").hover(function(){ $("#DESC1").css("display", "block"); }, function(){ $("#DESC1").css("display", "none");});
</script>
```

and then you can turn that into a function etc.

PS: Again this uses jQuery so you need to implement it in the head section (preferably) and before this code anyway